# php,mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array while loop of <a href>

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am kinda new to PHP and I am buliding a music library as a school project.

There is a Table 'albums' which holds 'id' and 'name'.
and a table 'songs' containing 'id','name','album_id' and 'path'.

Long story short,I am trying to display all the songs that are in the selected album.
user creates an album and then uploads songs into it.that part works great and the DB is filled in correctly.
problem is, once I select an album to view the songs that are in it I get nothing.

```
        <?php
        $album_id = $_GET['id'];
        //display songs from selected album
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE album_id = $album_id");
        while ($fetch_songs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $song_name = $fetch_songs['name'];
            $song_path = $fetch_songs['path'];
            ?>
                    <a href="music/<?php echo $song_path ?>">play song</a>
                    <br/>
                    <b><?php echo $song_name; ?></b> 
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </div>
```

I believe using a href would be the simplest option, yet I've tried also audio controls and even trying to upload an image with img  src istead of an MP3 and still no success, I just get an empty page.

this is the code for song uploading to DB.

```
            if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $album_id = $_POST['album'];

                $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $random_name = rand();


                if (empty($name) || empty($file_name)) {
                    echo "Please fill all fields in the form ! <br/>";
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'music/' . $random_name . '.mp3');
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO songs VALUES ('','$name','$album_id','$random_name.mp3')");

                    echo "File uploaded ! </br></br>";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, including `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: nope,not getting any error report.

Comment: is albumid is not integer you need to enclose it in quotes

Comment: You mean like this? : ("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE 'album_id = $album_id'")
Doesn't seems to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
while ($fetch_songs = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

more information : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Still getting an empty album :(

Comment: echo $song_name and $song_path in while and copy the result here.

Comment: Mmm,that's weird. still nothing. so the problem is with the SQL query? cause its doesn't seems to read the data from the DB.

Comment: use "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE album_id = 1" ,at MYSQL(SQL tab) to check your query.

Comment: But 'album_id' is a varchar(yeah,I know,that's kinda stupid) its the name of the album. that's why there is the $album_id variable.

even if I'm trying :
("SELECT 'name','path' FROM songs WHERE 'album_id = Superunknown'")
To get that specific album I'm still getting nothing.